# In Grapher, can functions be used to define parametric curves?

Tags: grapher

I'm drawing a curve using matrices in Grapher, for instance:

[image]

However, any time I try to use a function (i.e. `a(x)`) as a matrix element:

[image]

I get errors:

[image]

I've looked through the unofficial manual, but it doesn't specifically say. If I'm not able to use a function as an element, I'd have to re-type the expression in multiple locations whenever I want to change it :(

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I know :) But I thought vectors are just a special case of matrices? And my question would apply to matrices as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just define function `a` in terms of `t` rather than in terms of `x`. For example, the following

[image]

produces 3 turns of a [helix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helix)

[image]

Comment: Great, thank you, that worked—I was expecting that the function definition just uses its own local parameters unrelated to any other definitions (which does seem more sensible, IMHO)